# Removing duplicates from Join with grouped result

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I use an sql server with EF Core. Due to lack of GROUP BY support by EF I run raw sql query.

So, I have a history table

```
+------------+---------+------------------+
| HardwareId | StateId |    Timestamp     |
+------------+---------+------------------+
| Dev1       |       1 | 2019-10-11 11:00 |
| Dev2       |       2 | 2019-10-11 11:01 |
| Dev1       |       3 | 2019-10-11 11:09 |
| Dev2       |       1 | 2019-10-11 11:10 |
| Dev2       |       2 | 2019-10-11 11:10 |
| Dev1       |       3 | 2019-10-11 11:11 |
+------------+---------+------------------+
```

Here some Device records can have the same timestamps.

Now I want to have the last state of each device:

```
+------------+---------+------------------+
| HardwareId | StateId |    Timestamp     |
+-----==-----+---------+------------------+
| Dev2       |       1 | 2019-10-11 11:10 |
| Dev1       |       3 | 2019-10-11 11:11 |
+------------+---------+------------------+
```

I run

```
SELECT H.TimeStamp, H.HardwareId, H.ErrorCode, SD.Description FROM History H
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT HardwareId, MAX(TimeStamp) LastDateTime from History 
GROUP BY HardwareId) AS LastStates 
ON H.TimeStamp = LastStates.LastDateTime
INNER JOIN StateDescription SD ON H.ErrorCode = SD.Id ORDER BY H.HardwareId
```

but it gives me duplicates (due to timestamp duplicates for a given device, kind of multiple last states of a device. I would prefer to select any of these states)

```
+------------+---------+------------------+
| HardwareId | StateId |    Timestamp     |
+------------+---------+------------------+
| Dev2       |       1 | 2019-10-11 11:10 |
| Dev2       |       2 | 2019-10-11 11:10 |
| Dev1       |       3 | 2019-10-11 11:11 |
+------------+---------+------------------+
```

adding DISTINCT fixes it

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.TimeStamp, H.HardwareId, H.ErrorCode, SD.Description FROM History H
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT HardwareId, MAX(TimeStamp) LastDateTime from History 
GROUP BY HardwareId) AS LastStates 
ON H.TimeStamp = LastStates.LastDateTime
INNER JOIN StateDescription SD ON H.ErrorCode = SD.Id ORDER BY H.HardwareId
```

but if I want to add a record Id **(H.Id)** to the final result I obviously get duplicates again.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT H.TimeStamp, H.Id, H.HardwareId, H.ErrorCode, SD.Description FROM History H
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT HardwareId, MAX(TimeStamp) LastDateTime from History 
    GROUP BY HardwareId) AS LastStates 
    ON H.TimeStamp = LastStates.LastDateTime
    INNER JOIN StateDescription SD ON H.ErrorCode = SD.Id ORDER BY H.HardwareId
```

How could I get some kind of TOP(1) record for each devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `row_number()`:

```
select h.*
from (select h.*,
             row_number() over (partition by HardwareId order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from history h
     ) h
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will select exactly one row per device per day.  If there are duplicates on the day, it will return an arbitrary value.  If you want all of them, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.